# LightGBM: Sklearn and Native API equivalence

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm experimenting LightGBM through Training API http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#training-api and Scikit-learn API http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api.

I've not been able to make a clear mapping between both API as highlighted in example below. The basic idea is to train on 50% of the synthetic dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import lightgbm as lgbm

# Generate Data Set
xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape((-1, 1)) 
ys = xs**2 + 4*xs + 5.2
ys = ys.reshape((-1,))

# LGBM configuration
alg_conf = {
    "num_boost_round":25,
    "max_depth" : 3,
    "num_leaves" : 31,
    'learning_rate' : 0.1,
    'boosting_type' : 'gbdt',
    'objective' : 'regression_l2',
    "early_stopping_rounds": None,
}

# Calling Regressor using scikit-learn API 
sk_reg = lgbm.sklearn.LGBMRegressor(
    num_leaves=alg_conf["num_leaves"], 
    n_estimators=alg_conf["num_boost_round"], 
    max_depth=alg_conf["max_depth"],
    learning_rate=alg_conf["learning_rate"],
    objective=alg_conf["objective"]
)
sk_reg.fit(xs[::2], ys[::2])

print("Scikit-learn API results")
print(sk_reg.predict(xs[1::2]))


# Calling Regressor using native API 
train_dataset = lgbm.Dataset(xs[::2], ys[::2])
lg_reg = lgbm.train(alg_conf.copy(), train_dataset)

print("Native API results")
print(lg_reg.predict(xs[1::2]))
```

## Output

```
Scikit-learn API results
[  14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851
   14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851   14.35693851
   25.37944751   25.37944751   25.37944751   25.37944751   25.37944751
   35.10572544   35.10572544   35.10572544   35.10572544   35.10572544
   46.50667974   46.50667974   46.50667974   46.50667974   46.50667974
   59.44952419   59.44952419   59.44952419   59.44952419   59.44952419
   75.42846332   75.42846332   75.42846332   75.42846332   75.42846332
  109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814
  109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814
  109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814   109.4610814 ]
Native API results
[ 22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971
  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971
  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971
  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971  22.55947971
  45.33537795  45.33537795  45.33537795  45.33537795  45.33537795
  91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959
  91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959
  91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959
  91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959
  91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959   91.6376959 ]
```

## Question

Where could I find a clear equivalence between both API parameters ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I obtained the answer on LightGBM GitHub. Sharing the results below:

Adding `alg_conf "min_child_weight": 1e-3, "min_child_samples": 20)` fixes the difference:

```
import numpy as np
import lightgbm as lgbm

# Generate Data Set
xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape((-1, 1)) 
ys = xs**2 + 4*xs + 5.2
ys = ys.reshape((-1,))

# Or you could add to your alg_conf "min_child_weight": 1e-3, "min_child_samples": 20.

# LGBM configuration
alg_conf = {
    "num_boost_round":25,
    "max_depth" : 3,
    "num_leaves" : 31,
    'learning_rate' : 0.1,
    'boosting_type' : 'gbdt',
    'objective' : 'regression_l2',
    "early_stopping_rounds": None,
    "min_child_weight": 1e-3, 
    "min_child_samples": 20
}

# Calling Regressor using scikit-learn API 
sk_reg = lgbm.sklearn.LGBMRegressor(
    num_leaves=alg_conf["num_leaves"], 
    n_estimators=alg_conf["num_boost_round"], 
    max_depth=alg_conf["max_depth"],
    learning_rate=alg_conf["learning_rate"],
    objective=alg_conf["objective"],
    min_sum_hessian_in_leaf=alg_conf["min_child_weight"],
    min_data_in_leaf=alg_conf["min_child_samples"]
)
sk_reg.fit(xs[::2], ys[::2])

print("Scikit-learn API results")
print(sk_reg.predict(xs[1::2]))


# Calling Regressor using native API 
train_dataset = lgbm.Dataset(xs[::2], ys[::2])
lg_reg = lgbm.train(alg_conf.copy(), train_dataset)

print("Native API results")
print(lg_reg.predict(xs[1::2]))
```

It works fine.

Comment: In Lightgbm Scikit learn api we can `print(sk_reg )` to get lightgbm model/params. do you know how to do this in native api? print(lg_reg) will return reference to object booster.

Comment: why are the results for the two APIs similar after changing the 2 parameters and not before?